# Keep info about deleted entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

In our project we need the ability to say who and when delete some entity.
So after some investigation I've found the next solutions:

1. Add IsDeleted and DeletedBy columns to every table and set it before deletion (Using delete event of NH). But here is some drawback of this solution: we have many sql views which should work only with non deleted data. So to achieve this we should write View over each Table which will be something like a filter. (WHERE IsDeleted = 0)
2. Serialize to xml each entity before deletion and store it in single separate table with the next structure: `Id | XML | Deleted By`

From your point of view which of these solutions is prefered, or maybe there are other solutions I didn't mention above?

**P.S.** The deleted rows should be excluded from queries (Both Nhibernate and SQL).

Comment: I would also consider database triggers

Comment: You could also consider an archived table. A quick tip, if you have a nullable `DeletedBy` column `IsDeleted` is pretty much redundant, because `Deletedby` != NULL means deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your note, Ben. Oleksii, the database triggers don't know anything about user of the application who deleted the row, or maybe I missed the idea of your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three options:

1. Hard delete.  The rows do not exist.
2. Soft delete.  As you describe.  Yep, you'll have to tack on IsSoftDeleted checks EVERYWHERE.  EVERYWHERE.  EVERYWHERE.  Its a total pain.
3. Archive table.  Create a table that is an exact replica of the existing table...and do the move (to the archive table) and the delete (from the original table) in a transaction.

I've worked with #2 an #3.  I prefer #3 because you avoid the EVERYWHERE additional clauses.

With #2, you may also have to figure out constraints that allow for 1 non-soft-deleted row (based on the unique constraint) but also allow duplicates of soft-deleted-rows that violate the unique-constraint.  Yep, good times.